# How to cascade delete replies from a post when deleting a post?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger, cascading-deletes

I allow my users to sort by reply count and have it indexed so the operation is fast. I maintain the reply count of posts with the following SQL (there is also an equivalent set of two functions for the incrementing half):

```
CREATE TRIGGER post_reply_count_decrement_update
BEFORE DELETE ON
public.convo_reply for each row execute function trigger_function_decrement_reply_count();
```

-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trigger_function_decrement_reply_count()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
   UPDATE post SET reply_count = reply_count - 1 WHERE post.convo_id = OLD.convo_id;
   RETURN OLD;
END;
$function$;
```

I am now trying to run this command: `DELETE FROM convo WHERE convo_id = 1000031;`

Unfortunately, it's not working, and is giving me this error:

```
SQL Error [23503]: ERROR: insert or update on table "post" violates foreign key constraint 
"post_convo_id_fk"
  Detail: Key (convo_id)=(1000031) is not present in table "convo".
  Where: SQL statement "UPDATE post SET reply_count = reply_count - 1 WHERE post.convo_id = OLD.convo_id"
PL/pgSQL function trigger_function_decrement_reply_count() line 3 at SQL statement
SQL statement "DELETE FROM ONLY "public"."convo_reply" WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "convo_id""
```

I believe this is occurring because the `convo` entry is deleted and then the value returns NULL in the trigger, so then the trigger errors out.

However, this is a non-problem, because the reply count is going to be set to 0 in a moment anyways after the post is deleted. Perhaps there is a way to just disable the trigger somehow while this is running? (although I still want it to be running for other posts of course)

I also would like to keep the trigger reasonably fast, because it runs every time a reply is created or destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try disabling specific trigger before running query

```
ALTER TABLE public.convo_reply DISABLE TRIGGER post_reply_count_decrement_update;
```

or catch violation

```
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
....
```

or check if the post exists, change the overall logic. Run trigger on post table for example, change table where your index is created...